# Как в программе на C++ под Red Hat Linux работать с переменными окружения?

Tags: c++, linux, redhat

Подскажите пожалуйста, какой код написать в программе на C++ под RedHat Linux чтобы добавить, изменить или удалить переменную окружения самой этой программы? Какие функции для этого используются?

Получить переменную окружения getenv() насколько понимаю. Также можно из третьего необязательного параметра функции main() в соответствии с POSIX. Но мне в данном случае нужно чтобы программа добавляла сама себе переменную окружения. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: [man 3 setenv](https://linux.die.net/man/3/setenv)

Comment: См. так же: clearenv(3), getenv(3), putenv(3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> мне в данном случае нужно чтобы программа добавляла сама себе
>   переменную окружения. Как это можно сделать?

В man написано:

> Функция  setenv()  добавляет  переменную name в окружение со значением
>   value, если        name ещё  не  существует.